# Retrieving response from PHP OData SDK when using SaveResult method

Tags: php, http, sdk, odata, odata-php-sdk

I am using the PHP Odata SDK (http://odataphp.codeplex.com/). The documentation and community seems to be very limited.

I am attempting to save an object to the OData service and retrieve the response. When I execute the method, it successfully saves the object to the OData service, but just returns a successful or true result. It should return the ID of the object I just added (which it does).

```
$user = Users:CreatUser(array_of_data);
$proxy->AddUser($user);
$proxy->SaveResult();
```

How do I retrieve the actual response from the OData Service?

I have tried:

```
$result = $proxy->SaveResult();
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the newly created entry should be returned in the Location header of the response, per the AtomPub specification.

If you were to surf to the location returned by the server in response to a successfully created entry, you should see an entry that looks exactly like the one in the HTTP POST response.

Comment: I realize this, but what I am referring to is what object/method do I call in the SDK to view this information? The SaveResult method simply returns true|false, if that.